# CRT decomposition in NTT for BFV

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, ring-lwe

AS explained in [section 4.5](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/510.pdf), decomposition for relinearization (2nd step of ciphertext multiplication in bfv) can be done using RNS components of ciphertext. In other words, they proposed a way to do CRT decomposition. My question, if it is possible to do this CRT decomposition when the polynomial is in NTT (point- value) form.

My understanding of NTT is very little, but it looks like NTT representation is friendly to multiplication and addition, and CRT decomposition requires something like modulus switching.

I will really appreciate it if you could share some useful references.